# Set then Select

Tags: mysql, sql, set, selection

Can somebody please help me with this simple (but I don't know how) task?

In order to avoid wasting time fixing every single line, I'm trying to do something like this

```
    SET @auditor = a, b, c;

    SELECT *
    FROM Audits
    WHERE auditor in (@auditor)
```

My query indeed is really long and this part "WHERE auditor in (@auditor)" will be repetitive. Therefore, doing some kind of Set first will make it faster to update when there are some changes in the work force (we hire "d" and/or "b" left)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not super clear what you're trying to do here since you only included a snippet. Why is auditor not a table? Then you can simply add or remove records and join or select from the auditor table to determine if they exist. Or better yet, don't delete records but have a flag to mark them as terminated or not so you don't lose historical data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array variable and [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SET @auditors = 'a,b,c';

SELECT *
FROM Audits
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(auditor,@auditors)
```

Explanation: 
`FIND_IN_SET(auditor,@auditors)` is true is auditor is found in `@auditors` and in this case it returns the index.

But I would consider saving the auditors in a separate table rather than in a variable to better keep track of them.

Comment: This is great. And thanks for your recommendation about having a separate table for the auditor. Trust me I'd love that but it's undo-able at the moment for me.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a temporary table at the top of your query instead:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE FilteredAudits AS (SELECT * FROM Audits WHERE Auditor IN (a,b,c))
```

Then replace `Audits` with `FilteredAudits` as needed.

The benefits to this approach is that you guarantee the filter will only be applied once, meaning the rest of the query will `JOIN` to the smallest data set possible, and you don't have to repeat your `IN()` filter throughout the query.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set a parameter like an array. you will have to do something like

set @auditor='a,b,c'

now if auditor is a number this should work but if it is anything other then you will have to create a funciton dbo.[tfn_SplitList] on your system you will use it like below

auditor in(select List from dbo.[tfn_SplitList](@auditor ,','))